# Export SCSS map to json format?

Tags: sass, gulp-sass

I am trying to find an easy way to export Sass maps to a json format so they can be used in my js as well. I have found multiple libraries around but they all are doing the opposite (from what I can tell) aka using js variables in sass.

**TL DR; Is there a way to export sass maps to JSON format?**

Preferably in gulp as I am using this for build automation.

Found libraries:

- [SassyJSON](https://github.com/HugoGiraudel/SassyJSON)
- [Scss to json](https://github.com/ryanbahniuk/scss-to-json) <= doesn't take maps
- [Sassport](https://github.com/davidkpiano/sassport#using-sassport-modules) <= does only the opposite (?) docs really unclear to me
- [Sassy export](https://github.com/ezekg/sassy-export) <= looks good, how to use in gulp?
- [Node sass export](https://github.com/Punk-UnDeaD/node-sass-export) <= can't get it to output a file, docs confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using the `node sass export` module, [the creator helped me solve my issue.](https://github.com/Punk-UnDeaD/node-sass-export/issues/1)

Comment: Hey did it work with non map variables for you ? I saw your conversations with the author on github and managed to run everything but variables like $spacer: 1rem are not inserted inside the json object

Comment: I'm not sure, I only needed it to work with maps. Hope you find it!

Comment: I see. I ended up forking and tweaking another library for my needs

Answer (score 2):

Hi a little late but have you tried this one?
[sass-export](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-export)

It is in early version but it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this npm package - [sass-json-export](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-json-export)

It returns a JSON inside the output CSS file. You have the option to have the JSON returned inside a media query or a comment.
This CSS file can be easily parsed to extract the JSON part into a separate JSON file.

Comment: Already made it work with `node sass export`, the creator helped me with my issue ;)